# Probabilistic proof of minimal number of disjoint pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $n \in \Bbb N$, $0 < \delta < \frac 12$ and let $\mathcal F$ be a family of $m=2^{(\frac 12 + \delta)n}$ subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$. [This paper (section 2)](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/Publications/The%20maximum%20number%20of%20disjoint%20pairs%20in%20a%20family%20of%20subsets.pdf) proves that the number of disjoint pairs from $\mathcal F$ is less than $m^{2-\delta ^2/2}$. I struggle with the end of the proof, which is as follows.

Let $A_1,...,A_t$ be subsets from $\mathcal F$ chosen idependently with repetitions, where $t$ is chosen so that the following happens:

$$\Bbb P[|A_1 \cup... \cup A_t|\leq \frac n2] \leq 2^{n(1-\delta t)}<\Bbb P[Y > 2^{\frac n2} ]$$
where $Y$ is the number of elements of $\mathcal F$ that are disjoint to all of $A_i$.

These two inequalities imply that there are $A_1,...,A_t$ such that $|A_1 \cup... \cup A_t|> \frac n2$. They also imply that there are $A_1,...,A_t$ such that $Y > \frac n2$.

However, the authors claim that there are $A_1,...,A_t$ such that both of these happen **simultaneously**, which I see suffices to finish the proof. But how do they know this? They don't derive anything on the probability that both events happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an inequality the wrong way round: they show that $|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_t|>\frac n2$ and $Y$ is sufficiently large.

What they actually do is get a lower bound $p$ on the probability that $Y$ is sufficiently large, and an upper bound $q$ on the probability that $|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_t|\leq\frac n2$. They say that "one can check that [for suitable $t$]" actually $p>q$. But if $p>q$ then $Y$ is sufficiently large more often than the union is too small, so sometimes $Y$ will be sufficiently large and the union will not be too small.

Comment: We have two events, $A,B$, with the probability of $A$ bigger than the probability of $B$. We want to conclude that with positive probability $B$ occurs and $A$ does not occur. And indeed, letting $C$ be the complement of $B$, $P[A] + P[C] > 1$ so $P[A \cap C]=p[A]+p[C]-p[A \cup C]>1-p[A \cup C] \geq 0$.